# Why wont my filtering functionality work on Heroku when it works on my Dev machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

So I have this page that paginates all member on my site, and I added an alphabet link to allow people to find members by their membername. It works fine on my dev machine but it just doesnt work on heroku.

My controller has:

```
  def artists
     @artists = Member.joins(:member_role).where("member_roles.artist" => true).page(params[:page]).per(20)
     @names = Member.joins(:member_role).where("member_roles.artist" => true).where("membername LIKE ?", "#{params[:letter]}%").page(params[:page]).per(20)

  end
```

and my view has:

```
  <% ('A'..'Z').each do |a|%>
    <%= link_to a, {:action => :artists, :controller =>:members, :letter => a } %>
  <% end%>


  <% if params[:letter].nil? %>
    <div class="content">
      <%= paginate @artists %>
    </div>

    <ol class="members_list">
    <% @artists.each do |member| %>....
```

So Im checking to see if there were any parameters passed in and if there are not then @artists is shown otherwise @names is. And it works perfect on my laptop but not in heroku

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is down to case-sensitivity.

Most builds of MySQL, which you say you are using, do not have a case-sensitive LIKE.

Postgres, by default, is case sensitive for LIKE.  To get around this use ILIKE:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name ILIKE '%a%'
```

(Note the wildcard '%' around the a)

You really should try to keep your dev env as close to production as possible in order to mitigate this sort of bug.  Use Postgres.

Comment: That brakes in mySQl:
` @names = Member.joins(:member_role).where("member_roles.artist" => true).where("membername ILIKE ?", "#{params[:letter.downcase]}%").page(params[:page]).per(20)`

Comment: Do you get an error?  Are you using Wildcard 5's either side of your string that you are i-liking?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

When you say it doesnt work - are there any errors?

You could try heroku log(s?)  to see if there are any errors.

What database are you using in dev?  Are you using postgres?

Heroku uses postgres which has some specific quirks - so if you are working with sqlite or mysql in dev, then its possible you might get different behaviour on Heroku.

And/or use postgres locally.

HTH, Chris

PS Heroku tips for [migrating to postgres](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#common_issues_migrating_to_postgresql)

Comment: no errors, clicking on a letter just reloads the page as is (http://rtattoos.com/members/artists?letter=G) and yes im using myswl on my dev machine